# How do I add support for "video/photo" attach from applications like whatsapp to my application?

Tags: android, camera, android-intent

I am writing a camera application for Android, I want my application to be listed when video/photo is requested to be taken in applications like whatsapp messenger.

For example, in whatsapp when you click attach picture you can select the stock camera, or if I install vignette, I can use vignette.

How do I know which intent to listen to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **Intent Filter** to do this.

```
    <activity android:name=".Activity" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If you add the Intent Filter with Data , category and data as given above , it will ask for Application if you need to share some Photos say Share Image outside of Application from image Gallery.

If you Select you application it will Redirect the Control to your Activity.

Inside you Activity you handle your Intent by using :

```
try{
        Uri imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("Exception eeee", ""+e);
    }
```

**Now cursor will contains your selected image**.

This is for Image chooser, you can use same for **Video** ,needed to change the **mimitype** in Manifest file of Intent Filter.

Comment: Wow! Great information! Thanks, I think this leaves only one thing for me to wonder about. Whatsapp sets a size limitation on the returning video.  How do I find out the max size it enforces?